# Adding numbers to an arraylist from the Jtextfield

Tags: arraylist, jtextfield

I am sure its very simple but this is my first java class. the user enters a number into the input Jtextfield. the Add button is supposed to add that number to the arraylist. I am having trouble figuring out how to do that exactly. Any help you can give me would be awesome

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayExercise extends JFrame
{


private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 300;
private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;

private JPanel panel1;
private JPanel panel2;

private JLabel messageLabel;

private JTextField input;
private JTextArea output;

private JButton addButton;
private JButton list;
private JButton rlist;
private JButton clear;


public ArrayExercise()
{
setTitle("Array Exercise");

setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

panel1();
panel2();

add(panel1, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(panel2, BorderLayout.WEST);

setVisible(true);
input.requestFocus();
}
private void panel1()
{
messageLabel = new JLabel("Input");
input = new JTextField(5);
addButton = new JButton("Add");
list = new JButton("List");
rlist = new JButton("R-List");
clear = new JButton("Clear");

addButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
list.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
rlist.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
clear.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));

panel1.add(messageLabel);
panel1.add(input);
panel1.add(addButton);
panel1.add(list);
panel1.add(rlist);
panel1.add(clear);
}
private void panel2()
{
output = new JTextArea(12, 10);

panel2 = new JPanel();

panel2.add(output);
}
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
    String in;
    int number;
    int index = 0;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();             

    String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();

    if (actionCommand.equals("Add"))
    {
    index++;
    in = addButton.getText();
    list.add(addButton.getText());
    if (index == 9)
            {
            input.setEditable(false);
            addButton.setEnabled(false); 
            }

    output.setText(in + " added.");
    input.setText(null);
    input.requestFocus();

    }       
    if (actionCommand.equals("List"))
    {
    for(int x = 0; x <= list.size(); x++)
    {
    output.setText((x+1)+ ".  " + list.get(x) + "\n");
    }
    }
}
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
new ArrayExercise();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you tried to debugged the code and find out the problem?

Comment: yeah I tried, but like I said this is my first java class so I don't get to much out of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You have ArrayList list which is not adding any string value to that list and you are trying to run that over loop to get you values. If you are not adding anything to list then how can you extract anything out of it.

```
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

For each button attach different actionlistener as all buttons are not supposed to act same way.

To add elements in ArrayList use this

```
   list.add(input.getText()); // adding text entered into input textfield.
```

Comment: i'm trying to add the numbers inputted into the Jtextfield when I click Add. i get the text, then I .add it into the array. Its not working so hot tho

Comment: i could add different listeners but thats why i have the if statements, even if i did the initial code isnt working for the add button

Comment: I update the code for how to add elements in ArrayList. For Debugging any code in eclipse you can get nice tutorial 
http://www.comscigate.com/debug/learn_Debug.htm

Answer (score 0):

- Make a list
- List item
- Make a TextField
- Make Button Add Listener to button
- Get  the text from the text field or text area Add to array list
  object

Here is all the work you need to do:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayObject= new ArrayList<String>();
JButton button = new JButton();
JtextField textBox = new JtextField ();

  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          //inside your action listener:
             String add_item_to_array = textBox.getText().trim();
             arrayObject.add(add_item_to_array);


        }
    });
```